# Iphone simulator User Album Photo

Tags: iphone, simulator, photo-gallery

I'm doing image modification on my iphone simulator using pixel value.

I created severals photo that I saved in the User Photo Album, and I want to get it back from the simulator to my imac. Where can I found the image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Media/DCIM/100APPLE
```

Comment: I do not have an 'Application Support' folder for OS 4.0 on my Imac.

Comment: I've tryed on OS 3.2 and it's the same problem. I don't know how to extract photo from the user album photo to my computer. :S

Comment: @Raphael: Are you sure? `~` means `/Users/<yourUserName>`.